# Android Minecraft always shows as Steve

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm new to Minecraft and have installed it on my daughters tablet.

She logs in with her MS child account.

On the main menu screen, if I tap on Profile I can see her User Name but on the main menu, she always shows as Steve! I am able to update the character's appearance so I know it's saving changes.

I have no idea who Steve is and I don't even know a Steve.

[image]

Is what I'm experiencing correct? Can I change the name Steve?

Comment: Steve is the male character in Minecraft, the girl's name is Alex. Have you tried going into a world yet? Does the name Steve still show up or is it her username?

Comment: Also we use the Pocket Edition tag for questions about Minecraft on tablets or on phones. The Minecraft tag is for the Java edition on PC.

Comment: Ah, thank you for explaining the tags. I will ask her to check, thank you @Robbie

Comment: The Minecraft tag is for java on PC? Bedrock is Bedrock edition for console.

Comment: @Big_Chungus no idea - the tag wasn't set by me : https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/362366/revisions

Answer (score 1):

In order to change this, go to settings, profile, then change the name. If this does not work, download the Xbox app, sign in with your Microsoft account, make a name in the Xbox app, and sign into Minecraft with the Xbox app, yet again on the profile. Hope this helps!